# PHP XOR strings

Tags: php, xor

I saw this code from [an answer on PPCG](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/53633/22867):

```
echo BeeABBeeoBodBaBdOdPQBBgDQgDdp^"\n\n\t8b\n\n\t\nb&\nb b  \n%%nb%%%\n%\nQ";
```

I know PHP casts undefined constants into strings, so the equivalent code is:

```
echo 'BeeABBeeoBodBaBdOdPQBBgDQgDdp' ^ "\n\n\t8b\n\n\t\nb&\nb b  \n%%nb%%%\n%\nQ";
```

The output of those are:

```
Holy Hole In A Donut, Batman!
```

Can someone explain to me how the XOR of those two strings produce that line of output?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [this official example](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php#example-132), using `XOR` on strings will operate on ASCII values of each respectly character, so in your example:

- `B` ^ `\n` = 66 ^ 10 = 72 = `H`;
- `e` ^ `\n` = 101 ^ 10 = 111 = `o`;
- `e` ^ `\t` = 101 ^ 9 = 108 = `l`;
- ...

[3v4l result](https://3v4l.org/WpAvk)

Comment: Well that was unexpected. I have exactly the same answer, although I was  busy looking up why `60 ^ 10 = 72` before I noticed that someone answered the question.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek That's quite normal in SO :) there's always someone faster than you for just a few seconds. I abandoned so many answer for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply applying an `xor` on two characters at a time throughout the string. This is done by the conversion to ASCII and then the result is the ascii values which is the difference of value between the two converted items. See [example 2](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) in PHP's documentation. So the result:

```
"B" ^ "\n" => 66 ^ 10 => 72 => "H"
```

And so on on through the entire string.